# Flexlayout don't work with *ngfor?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

ngFor don't seem to work for me with ngfor when the flex direction is "row", I mean it works but it puts the items on top of each other instead of side by side

```
<FlexboxLayout class="itemWindow" *ngFor="let imageUrl of matchItems" 
flexDirection="row">
                <StackLayout class="inventoryImage">
                        <Image width= "80" height="80" stretch="aspectFill" 
                         left="5" src="{{imageUrl}}" ></Image>
                </StackLayout>
</FlexboxLayout >
```

What am I doing wrong ? is there another way to do it? I tried with DockLayout but same thing is happening.

Comment: Nobody has a solution ? Isn't ngFor for Layouts organized by row supposed to be really basic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your components so I used divs, but the idea is pretty much the same.

```
<div fxLayout="row"> <!-- extra container with row layout -->
  <div class="itemWindow" *ngFor="let imageUrl of matchItems">
    <div class="inventoryImage">
      <div width= "80" height="80" stretch="aspectFill"
           left="5">{{imageUrl}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `div` tag before listItem and added `*ngFor` to it instead of `FlexboxLayout`. And it works

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
  <div *ngFor="let filterItem of activityFilters">
    <Label flexGrow="1" class="text-center" [text]="activityFilter[filterItem]"> </Label>
  </div>
</FlexboxLayout>
```